# insert data into varable in select statement in pgsql getting error in invalid type name

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function dbo.sp_MakeSyncRequest (
    ToID int,
    P_comment text,
    UserID CHAR(36))
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
declare 
IsExist int;
FromID int;
BEGIN
    select intLatestRevision into FromID from dbo.trnProjectDetails where intProjectID=ToID;
    select max(intSyncID) into IsExist from dbo.trnSyncHistory where intFromProjectID=FromID and intToProjectID=ToID;
    if(IsExist>0)
    then
        UPDATE dbo.trnSyncHistory set txtMakerP_comment=P_comment, txtRequestStatus='W', intMakerID=UserID, dtMakerDate=NOW() where intFromProjectID=FromID and intToProjectID=ToID and intSyncID=IsExist;
    else
        declare LastSync integer;
        select max(intauditid) into LastSync from dbo.trnAuditDetails where intProjectID=ToID;
        INSERT INTO dbo.trnSyncHistory (intFromProjectID, intToProjectID, intLastSyncID, txtMakerP_comment, txtRequestStatus, intMakerID, dtMakerDate) 
        VALUES (FromID, ToID, LastSync, P_comment, 'W', UserID, NOW()); 
    end if;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from dbo.trnAuditDetails
```

but that datatype intauditid -- integer

Comment: You can not declare variable after begin. it must be between `DECLARE` and `BEGIN`. SO place `LastSync integer;` before begin and remove it after else. your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should move `LastSync` to the top. Because you can't declare variables after the `BEGIN` statement. PostgreSQL only supports variables inside `DECLARE` before the `BEGIN` statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.sp_MakeSyncRequest(ToID INT,
                                                  P_comment TEXT,
                                                  UserID CHAR(36))
    RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    IsExist  INT;
    FromID   INT;
    LastSync INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT intLatestRevision INTO FromID FROM dbo.trnProjectDetails WHERE intProjectID = ToID;

    SELECT MAX(intSyncID)
    INTO IsExist
    FROM dbo.trnSyncHistory
    WHERE intFromProjectID = FromID
      AND intToProjectID = ToID;

    IF (IsExist > 0)
    THEN
        UPDATE dbo.trnSyncHistory
        SET txtMakerP_comment=P_comment,
            txtRequestStatus='W',
            intMakerID=UserID,
            dtMakerDate=NOW()
        WHERE intFromProjectID = FromID
          AND intToProjectID = ToID
          AND intSyncID = IsExist;
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(intauditid) INTO LastSync FROM dbo.trnAuditDetails WHERE intProjectID = ToID;
        INSERT INTO dbo.trnSyncHistory (intFromProjectID, intToProjectID, intLastSyncID, txtMakerP_comment,
                                        txtRequestStatus, intMakerID, dtMakerDate)
        VALUES (FromID, ToID, LastSync, P_comment, 'W', UserID, NOW());
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.trnAuditDetails;
```